# Using definition to show continuity at a point

Tags: real-analysis

Use the definition to show that $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)=x^2$ is continuous at $x=3$.

I am unsure on the $|x+3|$ part. This is what I have done so far. I am kind of unsure. Please advise.

Rough work: By definition $|x-3|<\delta$ $\iff$ $-\delta < x-3 < \delta \iff -\delta +6 < x+3 < \delta +6$

Proof: Given any $\epsilon >0$, there exists $\delta >0 $ with $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon /7} \geq 1$. So for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $|x-3|<\delta$, we have $$|x^2-9|=|x-3||x+3|<\delta |(x+3)|< \delta |\delta +6|=\delta ^2 + 6 \delta \leq 7\delta ^2 = 7(\sqrt{\epsilon /7})^2 =\epsilon$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we can choose $\delta$ ourselves, we may want to restrict $\delta$, for example $\delta \leq 1$. We take $\delta = \min\{1, \frac{\varepsilon}{7}\}$

Then we have $|x+3| \leq (|x-3| + 6) < \delta +6 \leq 7$.

We also have $|x-3| < \delta \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{7}$.

Therefore we have $|x+3||x-3| < 7\cdot \frac{\varepsilon}{7} =\varepsilon$.

Comment: the 7  delta ^2 part would be untrue if delta is less than 1 so what should I write to ensure that this is not the case?

Comment: True. You will have to write $\delta = \min\{... , ...\}$

Comment: then how should I present my final part? I cant do the equality signs anymore since delta is min{1, root(e/7)}

Comment: This exercise can be quite difficult and confusing at first, but when you see the trick, it is a great tool for solving these exercises. Therefore I shall write the solution.

Comment: shouldn't it be strictly less than 7 on the first expression?

Comment: No, because we say that $\delta = \min\{1, \frac{\varepsilon}{7}\}$. However, I should have said $\delta \leq 1$ in the first sequence, so I'll edit that. Other than that, do you understand it?

Comment: oh I thought you wrote $\delta < \min \{1, \varepsilon /7\}$ but yeah I do. thanks.